# Download plugins by javascript on Chrome, Safari

Tags: plugins, google-chrome, safari

I have implemented the plugin by NPAPI for Firefox, Chrome, Safari, but there is a issue for me is  how to download the plugin by JavaScript on Chrome, Safari?

I know the .xpi is a extension for Firefox, and I can write the script for downloading the xpi from server and Firefox will equip a xpi to Firefox extension folder.

But how can Chrome and Safari do for downloading the plugin ? As I know the Chrome should put its plugin dll on `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\plugins` folder, Safari should put its `C:\Program Files\Safari\Plugins`?

I'm appreciated for any infomation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do 'document.location = pluginurl' or "googlechrome.exe pluginurl"